# Can i use more than 2 recycler views in one activity android

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, android-recyclerview

I have a requirement where i have more than 1 horizontal scrolls in an app (in the image Red, Green and blue). Is it possible to achieve this via the new Recycler view or i have to simply use the horizontal scroll view. I tried to implement two recycler views one below the other in the same xml but only one showed up and the other didnt. It would be great if you could link me up to some tutorials.

XML LAYOUT

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/second_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/recycler_view"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView,secondRecyclerView; //myRecyclerView was its name
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter,adapter2;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager,layoutManager2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        secondRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.second_recycler_view);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        layoutManager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        secondRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager2);
        secondRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

       // DaTA to be populated in the app
       // same data is used
        Constants.demoDatas = new ArrayList<DemoData>();
        for (int i = 0;i < Constants.backgroundImages.length ;i++){

            Constants.demoDatas.add(new DemoData(Constants.backgroundImages[i]));
        }

        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(Constants.demoDatas,this);
        adapter2 = new SecondRecyclerAdapter(Constants.demoDatas,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        secondRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter2);

    }
```

[image: question]

Comment: Please, include some code in order to help to understand better the issue

Comment: show `XML` file maybe you forgot to `wrap_content` somewhere

Comment: what about row layout ?

Comment: @Williams its a relative layout . Should i use a Table layout ??

Comment: can you post that also

Comment: @Williams yup surely just editing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [reported bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74772). Somehow, wrap_content it's not working with RecyclerView. You could implement a custom LayoutManager or set the height programatically. I've been using this last option, but I don't like it really much. Let's hope it's fixed soon.

UPDATE: Also, [this library](https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager) solves the problem implementing the custom LayoutManager for you.

UPDATE 2: This is now fixed using Android Support Library 23.2 and above as you can read [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

Comment: But other apps have more than one scolling views so are they doing it with the help of HorizontalScollView ???
For reference app : FLIPKART app home screen has 5 horizontal scrolling so are they using Horizontal Scroll View ?

Comment: You could use more than one RecyclerView, but since wrap_content it's not working, it's like you are using match_parent, leaving no space for the other RecyclerViews. If you fix the height of each RecyclerView to, let's say 200dp, you should see all of them.

Comment: fixing the height worked for me. so it is a bug thats the inference i can draw

Answer (score 1):

I have found a library that allows wrap_content to be used with RecyclerViews. [Check it out!](https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager)

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will be helpful for somebody. I have put 2 recycler views one below the other with good result. It shows pictures on the whole screen size for both recyclers.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/images1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"  />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/images2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```